# C - How To Close All Threads In A ThreadPool When Queue Is Empty And Won't Recieve Any More Data

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, threadpool

Right now, I have an unbounded synchronous queue that enqueues data and sends a `dequeueReady` signal. The main thread will spawn a thread pool that will start to dequeue from this queue. However, there will come a point when the queue is closed and no more data will be coming in, at that point, I want all the threads to wake up and terminate.

Here is my queue implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "unbounded_queue.h"

struct Node { // These are private and not meant to be accessed by client code.
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Queue *initQueue() {
    struct Queue *queue = (struct Queue *) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));

    if (queue == NULL) {
        perror("Init Queue Memory Allocation Failed:");
        exit(2);
    }

    queue->head = queue->tail = NULL;

    queue->queueSize = 0;

    queue->jobComplete = false;

    pthread_mutex_init(&queue->lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&queue->dequeueReady, NULL);

    return queue;
}

void *enqueue(struct Queue *queue, void *item, size_t itemSize) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->lock); // FIXME: CHECK RETURN VALUES OF ALL THIS! IF IT FAILS,


    struct Node *tempNode = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    tempNode->data = malloc(itemSize); // Don't forget your null terminator
    memcpy(tempNode->data, item, itemSize);
    tempNode->next = NULL;

    if (isEmpty(queue)) {
        queue->head = queue->tail = tempNode; // If empty, head and tail point to the same thing.
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);
        return tempNode->data;
    }

    queue->tail->next = tempNode; // tail points to old tempNode. This says old tempNode now points to new tempNode
    queue->tail = tempNode; // Current tail also needs to point to new tempNode

    queue->queueSize++;

    pthread_cond_signal(&queue->dequeueReady);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock); // FIXME: Check return value

    return item;
}

void *dequeue(struct Queue *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->lock); // FIXME: CHECK RETURN VALUES OF ALL THIS! IF IT FAILS,

    while (isEmpty(queue)) {
        if (queue->jobComplete) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);
            return NULL;
        }

        pthread_cond_wait(&queue->dequeueReady, &queue->lock);
    }


    struct Node *tempNode = queue->head; // Get node to dequeue
    char *data = tempNode->data; // Need to store the data so we can use it later. Client is responsible for freeing this because it points to dynamic memory. This could be improved so the client doesn't have to do anything, but it's fine for now.

    queue->head = queue->head->next;

    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        queue->tail = NULL;
    }

    queue->queueSize--;

    free(tempNode);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock); // FIXME: CHECK RETURN VALUES OF ALL THIS! IF IT FAILS,

    return data;
}

void jobComplete(struct Queue *queue) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->lock);

    queue->jobComplete = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&queue->dequeueReady);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->lock);

    return;
}

bool isEmpty(struct Queue *queue) {
    return (queue->head == NULL);
}
```

From the main thread, I am creating the thread pool and starting up the threads by dequeuing from the queue. However, eventually, some of the threads will be waiting for a dequeue signal that will never come. Hence, I created the `jobComplete` function. Once the main thread realizes that `queue1` is empty, that means no more data will be coming in and we can call `jobComplete` and stop.

Here is how I am spawning the worker threads:

```
while (!isEmpty(queue1)) {

    // The main thread here will call a function that enqueues data to queue1 and queue2.
   // Data from queue1 is dequeued here and used. 

     while (!isEmpty(queue2)) { // While the queue is not empty, keep dequeuing and spawn a new worker thread.
        for (int x = 0; x < threadNum; x++) {
            pthread_create(&threads[x], NULL, wrapFile, dequeue(queue2));
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < threadNum; x++) {
            if (isEmpty(queue1)) { // If queue1 is empty, that means nothing else will be added to queue2.
                jobComplete(queue2);
            }

            pthread_join(threads[x], NULL); // Wait for thread to finish.
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run this, it won't detect that the queue is empty and therefore `jobCompleted` won't run. I don't know how to `join` threads that are done and broadcast to all the other threads that are asleep to terminate. As of right now, the queue is infinitely waiting for more data to be enqueued, but I know more data won't be enqueued because `queue1` is empty at this point.

Comment: Huh?  The work threads should be calling dequeue() and the pool threads should be created once, at app startup.  You don't need to create new threads for each task and you don't need to join them.

Comment: It is fairly easy to terminate all the work threads in a 'normal' thread pool.  Queue up a null and have the threads check dequeued tasks for null.  If found, requeue the null, clean up and terminate.  The null then runs around all the threads, terminating them all.

Comment: Your threads should be watching for jobComplete OR non-empty state on the queue as the predicate condition of the condition variable, only acting on the former (and thereby exiting) when the latter (items to process remain) is *false*.  This allows you to stuff the queue at whatever pace you want, and eventually when finished, set the jobComplete state of the queue. If there are still items in the queue they take priority of thread-termination until the queue is empty. Only then does the completion state take hold and the thread terminates.